# I want to print the following pyramid of number pattern

Tags: c

1
2 4
3 5 7
6 8 10 12
9 11 13 15 17

Following is the code in which I am not able to print the pyramid:-

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
                printf("%d ",i*j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where's 14? 16?

Comment: Difference between adjacent numbers in each row is always `2`? <== is this **the rule** to build the pyramid, perhaps (and no repeats)?

Comment: can you make it clear what is the pattern between each column.

Comment: But what rule determines the first number of the row?

Comment: The two next rows would be `14 16 18 20 22 24` and `19 21 23 25 27 29 31`?

Comment: each row only has odd or even numbers. The starting number for row `N` is the last number on row `N - 2` + 2?

Comment: @pmg The pattern I see is that start of each row is the middle(half way) of start of first number above and first number below (ie; next row should start with 12 as (9) is half way between 6 and 12 )

Answer (score 0):

You need to track both even and odd numbers .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int even=1,odd=2;
    int n=10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        int a= (i % 2 == 0);
        for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) 
        {
            if(a)
            {
                printf("%d ",even);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d ",odd);
            }
            even += a ? 2 : 0;
            odd +=  a ? 0 : 2;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that algorithm fail to stop at maximum number which is 17?

Comment: @ssd No ,it will work . Why you think it won't work???

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean and compact algorithm but sth like this would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char tmp[10];
    int n = 0, row = 1, odd = 1, even = 2, c = 0, selectOdd, fin = 0;

    printf("maximum number: ");
    scanf("%s", tmp);
    n = atoi(tmp);

    if (n != 0) {
        while (fin < 2) {
            selectOdd = row % 2;
            c = row;

            if (selectOdd) {
                while (c != 0) {
                    printf("%3d", odd);
                    odd += 2;

                    if (odd > n) {
                        fin++;
                        break;
                    }

                    c--;
                }
            }
            else {
                while (c != 0) {
                    printf("%3d", even);
                    even += 2;

                    if (even > n) {
                        fin++;
                        break;
                    }

                    c--;
                }
            }

            printf("\n");
            row++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simple

your algorithm is odd, even, odd,... and so on

so you start with odd number until reach line number
for next line is even and you can find start number with this

you just need find number at start of line and continue print number number
in each step you just need

```c
num += 2;
```

remember 'lineIndex' start from 1

```c
num = (lineIndex - 1) * 2 + lineIndex % 2;
```

this is a full code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int numIndex;
    int lineIndex;
    int num;

    for (lineIndex = 1; lineIndex <= 5; lineIndex++) {
        num = (lineIndex - 1) * 2 + lineIndex % 2;
        for (numIndex = 0; numIndex < lineIndex; numIndex++) {
            printf("%2d ", num);
            num += 2;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```